# laravel srmklive-paypal error GH008 while pushing to repository

Tags: laravel, git, github, paypal, git-lfs

I installed in my laravel application the paypal package from srmklive.
now iam not able to push my repository to github.

```
git push -u origin main
Objekte aufzählen: 1244, fertig.
Zähle Objekte: 100% (1243/1243), fertig.
Delta-Kompression verwendet bis zu 10 Threads.
Komprimiere Objekte: 100% (736/736), fertig.
Schreibe Objekte: 100% (776/776), 4.12 MiB | 3.10 MiB/s, fertig.
Gesamt 776 (Delta 519), Wiederverwendet 0 (Delta 0), Pack wiederverwendet 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (519/519), completed with 385 local objects.
remote: error: GH008: Your push referenced at least 2 unknown Git LFS objects:
remote:     619ee24c6d20e1087214ee3012db6273f6454925b610b3cdc855d9c0776f04ea
remote:     040873716d7524beef0403afa8d7f7e3b741320dbd17dd631ed9c552d4db56f4
remote: Try to push them with 'git lfs push --all'.
To https://github.com/***/uns-portal.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
Fehler: Fehler beim Versenden einiger Referenzen nach 'https://github.com/***/uns-portal.git'
```

does anybody know how to fix this?

i installed git-lfs removed the package and reinstalled it. i also deleted those two files and tried again but it wont work